# Calling multiple functions in Alloy.js cause my UI to stuck or pause for sometime

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-titanium

Calling multiple functions in Alloy.js cause my UI to stuck or pause for sometime i have tried SetInterval and Settimeout too but unable to get what i am looking for

Comment: Hi Faizy, 
Please provide example code for evaluation.So some one can give you best approach to fix your problem.

Comment: get_racing_today_new();
 get_betfred_odds();
 get_recent_result_new();
 get_racing_tommorow_new();

 var call = setTimeout(function() {

  var index = Alloy.createController('index').getView();
  index.open();

 }, 1500);

}